# ActionBarDrawerToggle doesn't accept String as parameter

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-drawer

the Red line is under "Open navigation drawer" and "Close navigation drawer"

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                drawer,
                toolbar ,
                "Open navigation drawer",
                "Close navigation drawer"

                );
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toogle);
        toogle.syncState();
```

[This picture shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDPLR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check constructor signature as you can see it accepts string resource, `int`, not `String`

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
        Toolbar toolbar, @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
        @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
    this(activity, toolbar, drawerLayout, null, openDrawerContentDescRes,
            closeDrawerContentDescRes);
}
```

You need to change both from `String` to string resource such as `R.string.YOUR_STRING` that located in strings.xml file.

Comment: Thank you very much "You need to change both from String to string resource with R.string.YOUR_STRING in strings.xml file" That's the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

> According to Android official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int)) openDrawerContentDescRes and closeDrawerContentDescRes are of int datatype.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, 
            DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
            int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
            int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

So you need to change your string to string resource id ( `R.string.YOUR_STRING`) to describe the "open drawer" and "close drawer" action for accessibility.